# Not getting focus on list rows in android

Tags: android

I have a list with some rows which define some transaction. When i select the row, particular transaction details is showing in another list. Now when i am selecting a row in the first list, corresponding details is showing in the second list but the first list's selected row is not getting the focus. How can i get the focus?? I am doing this for android tablet and OS is 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use listview.setSelection(int postion)

It Changes the selection state of this view. A view can be selected or not. Note that selection is not the same as focus. Views are typically selected in the context of an AdapterView like ListView or GridView; the selected view is the view that is highlighted.

Comment: public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) 
  {
   m_lvTransactions.setSelection(position);
   displaySelectedTransDetails(position);
  }                                                                                          i put the code like this..but its not effecting.